# How to include a symbol \S before the References in the TOC with includepdf?

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, koma-script

The following MWE generates a white pdf that just contains a number “1” indicating its page number. Name it `White.tex` and make sure its output is named `White.pdf`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\phantom{a}
\end{document}
```

Further, consider this other MWE, which relies on `pdfpages` to import the `White.pdf`. **What I would like to achieve is a `\S.` and the corresponding white space before the title `References`.** Otherwise, as can be seen in the output below, the title `References` looks weird. I do not want `References` to be numbered because in my true document, the `References` section is unnumbered.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,numbers=endperiod]{scrbook}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage{pdfpages} % To include the cover.

% TOC SETTINGS

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0pt]{default}{section}

\renewcommand\addchaptertocentry[2]{\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{#2}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\vfill
\tableofcontents
\vfill
\hspace{0pt}
\protect\thispagestyle{empty}
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={
    1,chapter,1,Fancy Paper Title,chap1,
    1,section,1,Fancy Title,1.1,
    1,addsec,1,References,1.6}]{White.pdf}
    
\end{document}
```

This is the output of the second MWE

[image: output]

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,numbers=endperiod]{scrbook}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage{pdfpages} % To include the cover.

% TOC SETTINGS

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0pt]{default}{section}

\renewcommand\addchaptertocentry[2]{\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{#2}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    
    \vfill
    \tableofcontents
    \vfill
    \hspace{0pt}
    \protect\thispagestyle{empty}
    \includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={
        1,chapter,1,Fancy Paper Title,chap1,
        1,section,1,Fancy Title,1.1,
        1,addsec,1,\protect\S.\hskip3.55ex References,1.6}]{White.pdf} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How did you figure out the `\hskip3.55ex`?

Comment: @Hector +1 Used the bisection method :-)